# Ruby spreadsheet hiding a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, spreadsheet

I am having problems with hiding one of my column in the spreadsheet. 
I use **spreadsheet** gem(spreadsheet (0.6.5.9, 0.6.5.5))

i made the entire workbook and trying to hide the 7th column in all the sheets.

```
workbook.worksheets.each do |sheet|
  sheet.column(7).hidden = true
end
```

this is not doing it.

Let me know if anybody got it to work

Thanks
Ramya

Comment: Seems you are not the first with this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066016/hiding-columns-with-spreadsheet-gem

Comment: It works but it looks like its not working. What it does it hides the column completely and also the columns are like array hence the index will start from zero.